# How to access hudi metrics

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-hudi

How can the Hudi metrics be accessed programatically. After a commit I would like to get metrics like records updated / records inserted and log them into a database.

I tried setting `hoodie.metrics.on=true` and `hoodie.metrics.reporter.type=INMEMORY`. But how can I get a `HoodieMetrics` object that contains the actual information?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?